# Make sure string only contains certain characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string and I want to make sure it only contains characters in `BSEO|0123456789`. I tried to do that with this regex

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[BSEO|0123456789]");
if (r.IsMatch(str)) throw new Exception("Invalid character.");
```

but it doesn't behave correctly, (e.g. string `SE` throws exception). What am I doing wrong, how can I fix it, and is there a better solution to this than using regex?

Comment: Does the string contain multiple lines? Is the pipe allowed or are you denoting an or (which is not allowed in a character set)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>You can use linq:</s>

```
if (str.Distinct().Except("BSEO|0123456789").Any())
    throw new Exception("Invalid character.");
```

**EDIT**

After pondering this for a while, I think the call to `Distinct()` may be a failed attempt at micro-optimization.  If performance is important, try with and without.  It may well perform better without.

**EDIT 2**

I am now convinced that `Distinct()` makes the query run more slowly.  Use this instead:

```
if (str.Except("BSEO|0123456789").Any())
    throw new Exception("Invalid character.");
```

Comment: I upvoted both answers, but I like this one better, it's more readable to me.

Comment: @PeterOlson thanks for the accept.  Please see the edited answer; the cleaner `str.Except("BSEO|0123456789").Any()` may well run faster.

Answer (score 4):

Right now you are matching a string which can start with one of those characters, but could contain any other character afterwards. Also you throw an exception when you actually do have a match which I guess is the opposite of what you want to do. Try this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[BSEO|0123456789]+$");
if (!r.IsMatch(str)) throw new Exception("Invalid character.");
```

The `^` matches the start of the string. The `+` denotes that any of the characters in `[]` should appear at least one time. The `$` matches the end of the string. So it says:
The beginning of the string should be followed by a sequence containing one or more characters from inside the `[]` which the should be followed by the end of the string.

Comment: This way, wouldn't that mean you could have whatever characters at the beginning before the match at the end?

Comment: @PeterOlson: No, the `^` stands for the beginning of the string. I extended my answer

Comment: Oh. That's my problem. I thought `^` mean *not*, like in Javascript regex.